# How to deal with application crashes with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Recently, I have implemented RabbitMQ for a couple of use cases. Sending mails is one of them (which is quite common in practice)

**My Problem Statement**:

A web service(say service A) needs to publish 1000 messages in the queue (which will be picked by some mail sending engine). But unfortunately, after publishing 500 messages to the queue, my app crashes.

Now, if I hit the same service again then the 500 messages that were already pushed in the first go will be pushed again. Though the mails duplication isn't a big deal for now, but is definitely not desired. How to deal with this one. Any thoughts ?

*Solutions that I came up with*:

1. Using the batch feature - but it is not supported by AsyncRabbitTemplate so I'm restrained from using that.
2. Using the database. But that's definitely cumbersome. I won't use this one as well.

Comment: did you try to commit the messages in one transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify the duplicates, you can use the [Idempotent Receiver](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/IdempotentReceiver.html) enterprise integration pattern on the consumer side.

Spring Integration [has an implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver).

However, it's not clear why you are using the async template since that is for send and receive operations. This application sounds like it only needs to send the requests, not wait for a reply.

It's also not clear how batching can help since the crash could occur on the consumer side after it has processed half of the batch.

In either case, you need to track where you got to before the crash.

Comment: Yup, I can replace the async template with the rabbit template for sending mails. Just thought of using it if in case I need to have any callbacks on success or failures.



And I have the sender and receiver in the same application so if I publish 1000 messages in a batch and 500 of them got consumed then they are removed from the queue instantly. And lets say app restarts. So now, only remaining 500 will be picked from the queue.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can still get async publisher confirms/returns with the standard template. No, the message will be requeued if the consumer fails during the first batch - as long as you use the default ack mode (AUTO). If ack mode is NONE, you would lose the message. However, you will still have to deal with the duplicate emails you've already sent when the requeued message is redelivered.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I'll use the standard template for this use case. And will look more into idempotent receiver if mail duplication poses a serious problem which I hope should not be the case.